# TensorFlow video processing, changes detection

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, video-processing

I'm newbie with machine learning, and I have only basic knowledge in neural networks.

I have pretty clear task:

**1.** Video stream shows static picture (white area with yellow squares)
(in different videos squares located in different places)

[image: video stream content example]

**2.** In some moment content of the video changes, and starts to show white area without some of the yellow squares.

[image: video content changed]

**3.** I need to create mechanism which can determines and somehow indicates that changes.

[image: changes detected]

I'm going to use for that task TensorFlow framework. Could anybody push me in right direction? Or I'll be very happy to see list of steps to overcome the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that in order to detect a CHANGE you either have to provide two images to the NN and retrieve this information or you might want to consider RNN's - NN's that are capable of 'remembering' some data from one run to the next. Btw: Are you aware that (it sounds to me like) NN's are an overkill for this?

Comment: Is the static picture always the same? Or are there several "static" pictures across different video streams or even in the same video stream?

Comment: @RuDevel Did I understand correctly - you think, NN is not applicable for that task? Could you suggest smth to start with?

Comment: @kaufmanu Yes, there are several "static" pictures across different video. One video - one picture that might changes over time.

Comment: @IvanTalalaev no- I'd expect an NN to be able to do that. It's just possible that - as kaufmanu explained - your solution could be as simple as subtracting two (consecutive) Images. That **strongly** depends on *how static* your images are.

Comment: To clarify that: It should be *very easy* for a NN to learn such a subtracting strategy- but if you know a simple solution there's no point in training a NN for that task. Except for learning/experimenting purposes of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how the static picture looks beforehand, may be some background-subtraction would work? Basically you just subtract the static picture from every frame and check the content of the result. If the resulting picture is empty (zeros or close to it up to some threshold) there is no change to detect. If the resulting picture contains a region that is non-zero (may be above or below a certain manually tuned threshold), you detected a change in that region.

Comment: thanks, but any ideas how to strive against noize? "Bluring" is a common strategy, but may be there is something more effective?

Comment: The thresholding I mention should be able to handle some noise. Other than that I guess it's best to try and see how this simple approach performs and based on that develop more sophisticated strategies if needed. Good luck with your project!